# Is there any way to format a number with the request locale?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the create-react-app package and I have a component that is being rendered at the DOM. That component has a table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Song Name</th>
        <th>Spotify Views</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><a>Moments</a></td>
        <td id="views">6552742</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The number from td #views is displayed as 6552742 as expected, but I wanted to be displayed as 6.552.742 (or 6,552,742 depending on the locale) by only using React tags (using the request locale). Is there any way to do so?

EDIT: I implemented this,and it works... but it looks like a lot of code to me :(

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let arrayViews = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (let tdValue of arrayViews){ 
        if(!isNaN(tdValue.innerText)){
            tdValue.innerText =  Intl.NumberFormat(navigator.languages, { maximumSignificantDigits: navigator.maximumSignificantDigits }).format(tdValue.innerText);
        } 
    }
})
```

Comment: this requires js code and a number method

Answer (score 0):

the JS-Code Methode looks like:

```
function formatNumber(n) {
  if (n < 0) { throw 'must be non-negative: ' + n; } 
  if (n === 0) { return '0'; }

  var output = [];

  for (; n > 0; n = Math.floor(n/1000)) {
    output.unshift(n % 1000);
  }

  return output.join("'");  //looks like 6'552'742

}

var numbers = document.getElementsByClassName('views');

for (var index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {
  var elem = numbers.item(index);
  elem.textContent = formatNumber(parseInt(elem.textContent));
}
```

So that the JS-function *formatNumber* works with your html, you have to adapt your html as follows (change `id` to `class`):

```
<td class="views">6552742</td>
```

There are various formatting options. Here are some:

```
  return output.join(" ");  looks like 6 552 742
  return output.join(",");  looks like 6,552,742
  return output.join(".");  looks like 6.552.742
```

I hope I could help you with it!